# JMeter - Calling HTTP samplers in JSR223/BeanShell samplers

Tags: javascript, http, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

in *SoapUI* I had the **ability to execute test steps and http requests using JavaScript** to allow **more dynamic tests**. 
After facing some problems I moved to *JMETER*.

After searching other questions and the Jmeter documentation, I **can't find a way to call http samplers using the *JSR223/BeanShell* samplers** in *JMeter*. 
None of the built-in objects provided such method as far as I saw.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are you trying to do? you want to execute http sampler in test plan using script?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I want to execute an HTTP sampler inside the script to involve more test logic around it

Comment: You can add script in JSR element and assign to variable `condition` true/false and then use ${conditon} in `If Controller`

Comment: @user7294900 thats not good for me because I want to call multiple http samplers inside a loop, with changing variables, in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more details on your use case ?

JMeter philosophy is to combine Controller (if, while, loop, foreach):

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers

JSR223 pre/post processors :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor

with groovy and samplers.

I am sure your use case can be done using those components as we do on a regular basis very complex scenarios with them

Comment: I guess you are right, I haven't seem to conquer all of the controllers thoroughly. Thanks!